# Fibonacci Sunflower Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, fibonacci

I'm trying to plot out a fibonacci sunflower using tkinter. It is drawing correctly, but I would like to be able to draw the spirals as well. However, I can't figure out how to properly connect them. Any ideas?

[image: drawing]

and here is my code:

```
import math
from tkinter import *

def s5(n,r): #works better for first direction
    spirals = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        spirals.append(((r*(i**0.5),((i*(360)/(((5**0.5)+1)/2))%360))))
    return spirals

# convert to cartesian to plot
def pol2cart(r,theta):
    x = r * math.cos(math.radians(theta))
    y = r * math.sin(math.radians(theta))
    return x,y

# set size of fib sun
num_points = 200
distance = 15

# do the cartesian conversion
coordinates = [pol2cart(r,t) for r,t in s5(num_points,distance)]

# center for the canvas
coordinates = [(x+250,y+250) for x,y in coordinates]

# create gui
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master,width = 500,height=500)
canvas.pack()



# plot points 
h= 1
for x,y in coordinates:
    canvas.create_oval(x+7,y+7,x-7,y-7)
    canvas.create_text(x,y,text=h)
    h += 1

mainloop()
```

This is the result I am trying to achieve:
[image: goal]

Comment: are you aware the canvas has commands for drawing lines and arcs?

Comment: yes...i;m just not sure about how to go about creating the proper spirals

Comment: Finally some interesting stuff created with tkinter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting problem and I just sketched a possible solution. You can start  from 1 to 20 and add each number to 21 first. Meaning you should connect 1 to 22, 22 to 43, 43 to 64,...
and again connect 2 to 23, 23 to 44,....

This gives you one directions of pedals.

For the other direction you can do the same thing but starting from 1 to 34 and add 34 to each number. Meaning you start with 1 and add 34 to it. 1,35,69,... 2,36,70,...

These two figures show how these spirals look like:[image]

[image]

in fact these numbers are not magical these are coming from the fibonacci numbers and based on the layers of your spiral you should detect it. Therefore you always have number differences like: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34,55,...

Comment: Hmmm this would work perfetly, but Im trying to find a dynamic approach. The number of nodes in the image can be changed, and this wouldnt hold true for each case

Comment: in fact these numbers are not magical these are coming from the fibonacci numbers and based on the layers of your spiral you should detect it. Therefore you always have number differences like: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34,55,...

Comment: exactly, i'm just having trouble finding the right equation to properly detect which node should be next in the spiral

Comment: based on the layers of your flower, two consecutive fibonacci numbers are selected (say 21 and 34) and your number x is connected to x+21 and x+34

Answer (score 2):

The following version of your program actually draws the lines, but I haven't found the motive for the 21 and 34 steps yet. I suspect that has something to do with the numbers you are using in the s5 function (the '5').

```
import math
from Tkinter import *

class Fibonacci():
    def s5(self, n, r): # works better for first direction
        spirals = []
        for i in range(n+1):
            spirals.append(((r*(i**0.5),((i*(360)/(((5**0.5)+1)/2))%360))))
        return spirals

    def pol2cart(self, r, theta):
        x = r * math.cos(math.radians(theta))
        y = r * math.sin(math.radians(theta))
        return x,y

    def calculate_coordinates(self, num_points = 200, distance = 15):
        # do the cartesian conversion
        self.coordinates = [self.pol2cart(r, t) for r, t in self.s5(num_points, distance)]

        # center for the canvas
        self.coordinates = [(x+250,y+250) for x, y in self.coordinates]

    def plot_numbers(self, canvas):
        h = 1
        self.calculate_coordinates(num_points = 200, distance = 15)
        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            canvas.create_oval(x+7, y+7, x-7, y-7)
            canvas.create_text(x, y, text = h)
            h += 1

    def plot_lines(self, canvas):
        for delta in [21, 34]:
            for start in range(34):
                x0, y0 = self.coordinates[0]
                i = start
                while i < len(self.coordinates):
                    x1, y1 = self.coordinates[i]
                    canvas.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1)
                    x0 = x1; y0 = y1
                    i += delta

    def create_gui(self):
        master = Tk()
        canvas = Canvas(master, width = 500, height = 500)
        canvas.pack()

        self.plot_numbers(canvas)
        self.plot_lines(canvas)

        mainloop()

def main():
    f = Fibonacci()
    f.create_gui()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

To eliminate the center as the starting point, modify the plot_lines like this:

```
def plot_lines(self, canvas):
    for delta in [21, 34]:
        for start in range(34):
            x0, y0 = self.coordinates[start]
            print x0, y0
            i = start + delta
            while i < len(self.coordinates):
                x1, y1 = self.coordinates[i]
                canvas.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1)
                x0 = x1; y0 = y1
                i += delta
```

This gives: [image]

Comment: The numbers are coming from the fibonacci numbers.... You can also get the floral patterns using 13 and 21 too... having a smaller number means a more circular spiral with more number of nodes while a bigger number produces smaller spiral with lower number of nodes